# PhpStorm Npm and Gulp tool windows missing in some projects

Tags: npm, gulp, phpstorm

For all projects I have `gulpfile.js` in the project's root (also `bower.json`, `package.json` and `node_modules`).
In `PhpStorm Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Node.js and NPM` I can see all the (local and global) packages.

However, in some projects PhpStorm shows the `npm` and `Gulp` tool windows... and in other projects it doesn't.

Anybody else ran into this problem?
The only (**consistent**) **difference** between the projects that have those tool windows and the ones that don't is: the projects for which PhpStorm doesn't show those tool windows are using versioning (either svn or git). I have no idea as why this is happening :|

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved it...

So, while having the `gulpfile.js` open, I've right-clicked on the filename tab (works also on the file in the Project tab) and saw that in the right-click menu I have `"Show Gulp Tasks"`. Clicked on that and the `Gulp Tool Window` appeared... Same for `npm` (right click menu on `package.json`). And after that, those 2 tool windows also appeared in the menu: `View -> Tool Windows`.

It's still weird that on any project I use versioning, they're not already there by default. It must be a bug... But at least this solved my problem.

Comment: This seems to happen when your gulpfile.js is not in the root of the project/repo. And, this trick works in WebStorm as well, probably all JetBrains IDEs. Thanks!

Comment: @Geo242 I always have my gulpfile.js file in the root project folder which also is the root of the repo. But I just thought what other thing might be causing this issue: having other `gulpfile.js` files in node_modules or bower_components probably (so the IDE doesn't know which one to take into account, even though there is one gulpfile.js in the root?)... not sure, I haven't tested with a bare repo to make sure this is/isn't the case

Comment: @Geo242 By the way, I just saw that in fact I had specified in the question that "I have `gulpfile.js` in the project's root" (which also is the repo - always, I never have a repo in a subfolder). I don't know why you still said "gulpfile.js is not in the root" :| That's not the case.

Comment: @MrCroft Sorry, I meant to be less specific. My personal experience of this issue occurred when my gulpfile was not in the root. I know yours is in the root. I was just pointing out one possible reason it could be happening. Regardless, the fix is the same, so, thanks for that!

Comment: @Geo242 no problem, I just wanted to state in case anybody quickly assumes that also just by reading the comment, not carefully the question. I think my problem must have been because the IDE is thrown off by other gulpfiles in node_modules probably, although that doesn't make sense... But I can't find any "logical" explanation for the issue, other than "it's a bug" :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution similar to the OP's solution. I had duplicated a project, opened it in PhpStorm, the `gulpfile.js` file was in the root directory, but I was getting the `"No gulpfile found"` error message.

So after reading the OP's solution I right-clicked on the `gulpfile.js` filename tab, and in that menu I clicked on `Open In -> Terminal`, and the problem was solved for me.